# bootstrap background image not responsive to mobile devices

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, background-image

I am trying to put a background on bootstrap webpage. Background image is working fine when webpage is loaded to laptop or desktop. But the problem occurs when pages are loaded on mobile devices some of the part of the screen remains unfilled.

Following is my code:

```
<body style="background: url(img/backgroung.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed"
    style="-webkit-background-size: cover"
    style="moz-background-size: cover"
    style="-o-background-size: cover"
    style="background-size: cover"
    style="background-size:100% auto"
   >
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

probably you want something like that:

```
body {
background: url('img/backgroung.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```